# Oracle : constrained by the 32K limit on a VARCHAR2 variable when send mail

Tags: sql, database, oracle, email

I am trying to send HTML mail by  oracle stored procedure using

```
SYS.UTL_MAIL.send
```

But unfortunately body is limited by varchar length 32k which will be exceeded in a lot of scenarios.

what i can use instead of above method to send such long mails?

Comment: 32k is a really, really long email.  Consider using attachments.

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:494228200346768899

Comment: [UTL_SMTP](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/email-from-oracle-plsql). There are working example even with attachments.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`CLOB` or `NCLOB` datatype](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i3266):

> The `CLOB` and `NCLOB` datatypes store up to 128 terabytes of character data in the database. `CLOB`s store database character set data, and `NCLOB`s store Unicode national character set data. Storing varying-width LOB data in a fixed-width Unicode character set internally enables Oracle Database to provide efficient character-based random access on `CLOB`s and `NCLOBs`.

There are multiple examples available on the internet of how to then send `CLOB` values in an e-mail (unfortunately none of them detail the license of the code so I won't cross post):

- [Ask Tom: How to send more than 32K message](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4475295928047#4489323327471)
- [Ask Tom: Sending e-mail! -- Oracle 8i specific response](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:255615160805)
- Searching for "oracle utl_mail clob" will get lots more.
- Or you can use [JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) to create a function and upload it into the database with the `loadjava` utility (or `CREATE JAVA SOURCE`).

These solutions do not use `UTL_MAIL` - [AskTom's response to this question](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:494228200346768899) is:

> The interface to utl_mail for attachments accepts either a 32k RAW or 32k VARCHAR2.

*(I.e. you can't but there are alternatives - see the links above)*

Comment: @AhmedEmad - which method - `utl_mail.send`? You asked "what i can use instead", this answer clearly says to use an alternative, and there are examples using `utl_smtp`.